# #pragma warning - file specific?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, pragma, preprocessor-directive

Simple question, but I can't seem to find an answer in any reference material.

If I have a #pragma warning() directive, does the compiler only define that for the current file? Or is it propagated through #includes in other files in my project?

This is probably a wider question, which isn't necessarily specific to #pragma, but that is the case I am particularly worried about.

Comment: Where did you put the #pragma warning? A cpp file or a header file?

Comment: What is your compiler?

Comment: @Timo Geusch I haven't put the #pragma in yet, I was just wondering where I need to put it, I need it for multiple files. The compiler is VC 2012.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put the directive in a header, it will affect any other file that includes that header. It will also affect any headers included after you use it. If you are worried about affecting other files with your use of this, you can use `#pragma warning (push)` and `#pragma warning (pop)` to undo any changes you only want to make locally to one file.